# Which surah(s) include in each verse one of Allah's beautiful names?

Tags: quran, surah, asma-ul-husna

It is well known that in [surat al-Mujadilah (58)](http://legacy.quran.com/58) in each verse the name of Allah الله  is quoted.

I think that similarly it is possible that many surah's of the Quran may include in each verse the name of Allah or a synonym -meaning one of Allah's beautiful names- and I'd like to have a list of these surah's!

Comment: Would you count, for example, عَلِيمًا as a name or only a description?

Comment: @TheZ well strictly speaking it's an attribute, but I wouldn't be too stringy if you mentioned this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The somewhat surprising answer is that no Surah other than Surah Mujadilah includes a name of Allah in every verse.

These are the top 20 surahs in terms of percentage of verses that have Allah's names:

[image]

I counted only the 99 well-known names of Allah, and I only counted them if they had the "ال". Meaning "الْعَلِيم" counted, but not just "عَلِيم." I think that is what you were looking for but I am not entirely sure, so correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, another one is Hashr surah 59 ayas 23-24

Huwa Allāhu Al-Ladhī Lā 'Ilāha 'Illā Huwa Al-Maliku Al-Quddūsu As-Salāmu Al-Mu'uminu Al-Muhayminu Al-`Azīzu Al-Jabbāru Al-Mutakabbiru ۚ Subĥāna Allāhi`Ammā Yushrikūna

He is God; besides Whom there is no god; the Sovereign, the Holy, the Peace-Giver, the Faith-Giver, the Overseer, the Almighty, the Omnipotent, the Overwhelming. Glory be to God, beyond what they associate.

059-023 هُوَ‌ ‌اللَّ‍‍هُ ‌الَّذِي لاَ‌ ‌إِلَهَ ‌إِلاَّ‌ هُوَ‌ ‌الْمَلِكُ ‌الْ‍‍قُ‍‍دّ‍ُ‍‌وسُ
 ‌ال‍‍سَّلاَمُ ‌الْمُؤْمِنُ ‌الْمُهَيْمِنُ ‌الْعَز‍ِ‍ي‍‍زُ‌ ‌الْجَبّ‍‍َ‍ا‌رُ‌ ‌الْمُتَكَبِّ‍‍ر‍ُ‍‌ ۚ سُ‍‍بْ‍‍ح‍‍َ‍انَ ‌اللَّ‍‍هِ عَ‍‍مَّ‍‍ا‌ يُشْ‍‍رِكُونَ

Huwa Allāhu Al-Khāliqu Al-Bāri'u Al-Muşawwiru ۖ Lahu Al-'Asmā'u Al-Ĥusná ۚ Yusabbiĥu Lahu Mā Fī As-Samāwāti Wa Al-'Arđi ۖ Wa Huwa Al-`Azīzu Al-Ĥakīmu

He is God; the Creator, the Maker, the Designer. **His are the Most Beautiful** Names. Whatever is in the heavens and the earth glorifies Him. He is the Majestic, the Wise.

Comment: Verses 9 from surat al-Hashr doesn't include any name of Allah!

Answer (score -1):

Which of the Quran verses has in the name of Allah and in the verse too?

Comment: This looks like a question asked in the answer section see [answer] and further, the answer of that question is given in the answers of my question.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/66242)